# Configuring specific network card

Tags: c#, networking, configure

I'm trying to create a tool using C# that simply takes the network adapter configuration and then I can reconfigure them again.

I could have prepared how to get:

- IP address
- Subnet mask
- Default gateway
- DNS primary and secondary.

But I'm stuck for one week on how to set the upper details for an adapter (given NIC adapter name).

Pseudo code:

```
setNIC(NIC_AdapterName, ip, submask, DGW, DNS1, DNS2)
{
    NIC_AdapterName.ip = ip;
    NIC_AdapterName.subnetmask = submask;
    .
    .
    .
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: -1 and close vote. **1.** What exactly is it that you want to configure? What "upper details"? It's completely unclear what kind of answer you expect. **2.** Why did you tag this question with C#? Your pseudocode doesn't look like C# at all. **3.** What are we supposed to take away from that pseudocode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Achieve what you want using the `System.Management` namespace

```
public static class NetworkConfigurator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Set's a new IP Address and it's Submask of the local machine
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ipAddress">The IP Address</param>
    /// <param name="subnetMasks">The Submask IP Address</param>
    /// <param name="gateway">The gateway.</param>
    /// <remarks>Requires a reference to the System.Management namespace</remarks>
    public static bool SetIPs(string sourceMacAddress,string[] ipAddresses, string[] subnetMasks, string gateway=null)
    {
        UInt32 res;

        using (var networkConfigMng = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
        {
            using (var networkConfigs = networkConfigMng.GetInstances())
            {                    
                using(var managementObject=networkConfigs.Cast<ManagementObject>()
                                                    .Where(instance =>
                                                             ((string)instance["MACAddress"])!=null)
                                                    .FirstOrDefault(instance =>
                                                             ((string)instance["MACAddress"]).Replace(":", "")==sourceMacAddress) )
                {
                    if (managementObject == null)
                        return false;

                    using (var newIPs = managementObject.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic"))
                    {
                        if (ipAddresses==null || 
                            ipAddresses.Length==0 || 
                            subnetMasks==null || 
                            subnetMasks.Length!=ipAddresses.Length)
                            return false;

                                newIPs["IPAddress"] = ipAddresses;// new[] { ipAddress };
                                newIPs["SubnetMask"] = subnetMasks;

                             res = (UInt32) (managementObject.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIPs, null).GetPropertyValue("returnValue"));
                            if (res != 0)
                                return false;

                        // Set mew gateway if needed
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(gateway))
                        {
                            using (var newGateway = managementObject.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways"))
                            {
                                newGateway["DefaultIPGateway"] = new[] { newGateway };
                                newGateway["GatewayCostMetric"] = new[] { 1 };
                                res=(UInt32)(managementObject.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", newGateway, null).GetPropertyValue("returnValue"));
                                if (res != 0)
                                    return false;
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set's the DNS Server of the local machine
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nic">NIC address</param>
    /// <param name="dnsServers">Comma seperated list of DNS server addresses</param>
    /// <remarks>Requires a reference to the System.Management namespace</remarks>
    public static void SetNameservers(string nic, string dnsServers)
    {
        using (var networkConfigMng = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"))
        {
            using (var networkConfigs = networkConfigMng.GetInstances())
            {
                foreach (var managementObject in networkConfigs.Cast<ManagementObject>().Where(objMO => (bool)objMO["IPEnabled"] && objMO["Caption"].Equals(nic)))
                {
                    using (var newDNS = managementObject.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder"))
                    {
                        newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = dnsServers.Split(',');
                        managementObject.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDNS, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you finding your way, here you will find the documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx